# error: variable set but not used when compiling using Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I am trying to compile and generated a shared library from [this](https://github.com/MolotovCherry/Android-ImageMagick7) repo. The process is initiated by the `ndk-build` command. I am getting an error during the compilation phase:

the ndk command that starts compilation is:

```
C:\sdks\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393\build\ndk-build --output-sync=none NDK_PROJECT_PATH=./ NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk NDK_OUT=./build/ NDK_LIBS_OUT=./jniLibs -j 4
```

output:

```
...
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : xml2 <= encoding.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : xml2 <= error.c
[arm64-v8a] Compile        : xml2 <= parserInternals.c
././libxml2-2.9.9/encoding.c:2397:12: error: variable 'writtentot' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    size_t writtentot = 0;
           ^
././libxml2-2.9.9/encoding.c:2570:9: error: variable 'writtentot' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int writtentot = 0;
        ^
././libxml2-2.9.9/encoding.c:2572:9: error: variable 'output' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]
    int output = 0;
        ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [C:/sdks/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393/build/../build/core/build-binary.mk:422: build//local/arm64-v8a/objs/xml2/./libxml2-2.9.9/encoding.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I understand the error: the warning is set to be treated as error.

I tried to disable this behavior by adding this to my `application.mk` file:

```
APP_CFLAGS   += -O3
APP_CFLAGS   += -Wno-unused-but-set-variable

APP_CPPFLAGS += -O3
APP_CPPFLAGS += -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
```

But nothing changed.

How can I disable the flag passed to the compiler by ndk-build and which is causing this error?

Comment: This specific option might be unknown in your version of the compiler. You might like to try to add `-v` to the options to see a verbose output of the compiler's call. Or to remove the `-Werror` from the options. An alternative to suppressing the warning is to correct the code, which I would favor.

Comment: @thebusybee "remove the -Werror from the options."  This is exactly what I am aksing about, how can I disable this flag which is sent to the compiler (which I am not sending, but ndk-build script is doing it seems)? I also ran with verbose log, and I saw `-Werror` being sent to the compiler in the compile command by the ndk-build

Comment: @thebusybee and fyi, I did as you suggested by editing the C files, and the warning (and consequently the error) is gone, and I am building successfully, but I would like to know how to prevent ndk from sending a flag that will make the compile command fail?

Comment: You want to search in the provided files for this option, and remove it. I suspect it to be somewhere in the *.mk files, but I'm not going to search it myself. -- If it is not there, you need to read the documentation of ndk-build how to control it. -- It's a (sad, but realistic) fact that some projects do not build out-of-the-box. You might consider to report an issue to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding this line to the file cflags.mk:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    += -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
```